# Getting incorrect result when checking a date between two other dates in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date, java-calendar

I'm using the code below to check if an hour is between two other specific hours:

```
String openHour = "08:00 AM";
String currentHour = "10:00 PM";
String closeHour = "11:00 PM"; //Change to 02:00 AM doesn't work!!!

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date openHourDate = format.parse(openHour);
Date currentHourDate = format.parse(currentHour);
Date closeHourDate = format.parse(closeHour);

Calendar openCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
openCalendar.setTime(openHourDate);

Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
currentCalendar.setTime(currentHourDate);

Calendar closeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
closeCalendar.setTime(closeHourDate);

Date open = openCalendar.getTime();
Date current = currentCalendar.getTime();
Date close = closeCalendar.getTime();

if (current.after(open) && current.before(close)) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect!");
}
```

If the `currentHour` is `"10:00 PM"` as you see in my code, everything works fine but if I change the change it to `"02:00 AM"`, the code doesn't work as expected even if the `currentHour` is between `08:00 AM` and `02:00 AM`. How to solve this?

Comment: Does it maybe have to do with the fact that your program is seeing the `02:00AM` as being on the same day?  If that were the case, you are saying the close time is `02:00 AM` on today but the open time is `08:00 AM` on the same day.  You would need to add a day to your close time if it was the next day.

Comment: You have tagged your question with java 8 so take a look at LocalTime and other similar classes introduced with this version of the JDK

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is what I have done in the latest hours without any luck :(

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I'm not sure I understand. Yes the `02:00 AM` is the second day but my `currentHour` is in between. You say to add a day, where, how?

Comment: You can add a day by using a class such as `LocalDateTime`

Comment: So it's kind of a tricky thing to explain through text but I'll try.  Your `close` value is getting an instance of a Calendar object and just setting the time right?  That means that your `open`, `current` and `close` are set the current date.  What this means is you are looking at `open` being equal to `4/9/2019 0800 AM` and close being `4/9/2019 0200AM`.  When you run your check, your `current` set to `4/9/2019 1000PM` is not before `close` because `close` is set for 0200AM the same day as `current`.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I see that now. Can you please provide an answer with the way in which I should add a day? Thanks!

Comment: The answer given by Richard should be a good starting point to get you going.  If it works don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer so others can see it :-)

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Just solved it using Richard Wheeldon's answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this issue.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Yes you're right. Just accepted Richard Wheeldon's answer. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) that also correctly handles current and closing time being after midnight.

```
String openHour = "08:00 AM";
String currentHour = "01:00 PM";
String closeHour = "02:00 AM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" , Locale.US );
LocalTime openTime = LocalTime.parse(openHour, formatter);
LocalTime currentTime  = LocalTime.parse(currentHour, formatter);
LocalTime closeTime = LocalTime.parse(closeHour, formatter);

boolean isOpen = false;
if (closeTime.isAfter(openTime)) {
  if (openTime.isBefore(currentTime) && closeTime.isAfter(currentTime)) {
    isOpen = true;
  }
} else if (currentTime.isAfter(openTime) || currentTime.isBefore(closeTime)) {
  isOpen = true;
}

if (isOpen) {
  System.out.println("We are open");
} else {
  System.out.println("We are closed");
}
```

Comment: Wow, solved my entire problem. This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just need to roll the day, as Michael Platt suggested:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String openHour = "08:00 AM";
    String currentHour = "10:00 PM";
    String closeHour = "11:00 PM"; //Change to 02:00 AM doesn't work!!!

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date openHourDate = format.parse(openHour);
    Date currentHourDate = format.parse(currentHour);
    Date closeHourDate = format.parse(closeHour);

    Calendar openCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    openCalendar.setTime(openHourDate);

    Calendar currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentCalendar.setTime(currentHourDate);

    Calendar closeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    closeCalendar.setTime(closeHourDate);

    if (closeCalendar.before(openCalendar)) {
      closeCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    Date open = openCalendar.getTime();
    Date current = currentCalendar.getTime();
    Date close = closeCalendar.getTime();

    if (current.after(open) && current.before(close)) {
      System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Incorrect!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. One more small question, if I change `closeHour` to let's say `01:00 AM`, is not working again, do you know why?

Comment: This solution is less than optimal. It is abusing date-time classes to hold time-of-day-only values. And it ignores the crucial issue of time zones, which are being applied implicitly using JVM’s current default time zone -- so your results may vary at runtime. We have a modern class for this work: [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html). So use it. See [Answer by Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599868/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for indicating the modern solution.