# How to traverse between a given time (i.e.11:00 am) and another time (i.e. 1:00 pm) in java?

Tags: java

I am making an Online Reservation System for a Restaurant in java. I want to know if a table is reserved. I have come up with this code.

I am not sure how to implement this logic.

```
public class Services {

    public void reserveTable(String tableSize ,int time_limit){         

        String starting_time = "11:00 am";
        String ending_time = "1:00 pm";
        String current_time = "12:00 pm"; //time at which new order arrived
        boolean reserved = false

        for (String start = "11:00 am"; start <= ending_time; start ++){
            if (current_time == start){
                reserved = true;
            }
        }        
   }         
}
```

Comment: You'll want to look at up `LocalTime` (and possibly `LocalDateTime`), [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) might be a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse your time strings into [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)s, and then check if the `current` is between the `start` and `end`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("h:mm a")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("11:00 am", formatter);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("1:00 pm", formatter);
    LocalTime current = LocalTime.parse("12:00 pm", formatter);

    boolean reserved = false;
    if (current.isAfter(start) && current.isBefore(end)) {
        reserved = true;
    }
```

Note that this won't work if the start and end span across midnight. e.g. `start` is 11pm and `end` is 2am. A `current` of 1am won't cause `reserved` to be set to true. For this case to work you need a date.

Comment: Actually you don't need a date for handling midnight, see my solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599868/9223839)